# How to download a file without available link but using selenium on click element

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to download automatically .zip file from a website using Selenium and Python

This is the code I tried to run :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

prefs = {"download.default_directory" : "C:/Users/toto/Downloads"}

options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

url = 'https://open.efsa.europa.eu/study-inventory/EFSA-Q-2022-00556'
driver.get(url)

downloadfiles = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Download all evidences')]")

downloadfiles.click()

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver. Quit()
```

I already tried using CLASS_NAME and XPATH with //span but I did not succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a working Selenium installation:

```
[...]
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
[...]
## define driver here, then
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
url = 'https://open.efsa.europa.eu/study-inventory/EFSA-Q-2022-00556'
driver.get(url)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[text()="Download all evidences"]'))).click()
try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[text()="I have read and I accept the terms"]'))).click()
except Exception as e:
    print('no confirmation needed')
print('done downloading')
```

Files will be downloaded -- ZIPped.

You can find [Selenium documentation here.](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/)

Comment: The code ran without any error but I don't see where the zip file is saved even if I change manually the location. From what I understand, the file should be saved at the same location of Chrome's preference.

Comment: The file will have been saved in the default Download directory (Chrome settings can be unreliable when setting a custom Download folder). And you should mark an answer as Accepted (green checkmark under voting buttons) if it solved your issue as asked.

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work for Chrome as browser but with Firefox as webdriver it does the job!